# Разделитель SVG между двумя растровыми изображениями

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, clip-path

Я пытаюсь создать разделитель SVG, который проходит между двумя растровыми изображениями. Я искал повсюду, и единственное, что мне подошло бы, вот  [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985981/wavy-border-separator-on-two-sections-with-background-images).

Однако ответ зависит от использования `body` (не такая уж большая проблема), а также без учета динамического содержимого, которое может увеличить высоту содержимого любого раздела. Любое другое решение, которое я нашел, основано на сплошном цвете, обычно белом. Решение вообще возможно?

Пример того, чего я пытаюсь достичь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG divider between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70041781/7394871) от участника  [@Mechwd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704816/mechwd).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/70041781/7394871

Answer (score 3):

### Пошаговое решение:

**Шаг #1.**
Два изображения добавляются в SVG, одно поверх другого с помощью тега `<image>`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 683" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
 <image  transform="translate(0,0)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg"
     width="100%" height="100%" />
 <image   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IAG.png" y="230" width="100%" height="108%" />   
</svg>
</div>
```

**Шаг #2.**

Для разделения двух изображений используется полоса с `pattern` SVG

В паттерн добавлены фигуры svg для создания рисунка
*Ниже добавлен код паттерна:*

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 683" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
<defs>

                 <!-- Shapes in SVG added to pattern -->
 <pattern id="patt" x="0" y="24" width="160" height="40"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" > 
              <g fill="black"  transform="translate(0,0)" >
  <g fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" >
  <path id="path837" d="M19.8 2.4 35 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M55.8-17.6 71-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path841" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M91.8 2.4 107 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" id="path845" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M127.8-17.6 143-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path847" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path id="path883" d="m55.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m127.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path885" />
  <path id="path887" d="m5.5-3.9 4 2.4V3l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m80-5.7 4 2.4v4.6l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path889" />
  <path id="path891" d="m152.7-5.4 4 2.3v4.7l-4 2.3-4-2.3v-4.7z" />
 </g> 
      </pattern> 
    
</defs>          
 
 <image  transform="translate(0,200)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg" y="-160" width="100%" height="100%"/>

  <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IAG.png" y="230" width="100%" height="108%" /> 
                <!-- Stripe with a pattern              -->
 <rect fill="url(#patt)" x="0" y="380" width="100%" height="40" fill="black"  />

</svg>
</div>
```

**Шаг #3.**

Добавляем маску, чтобы был виден фоновый рисунок сквозь прорези паттерна.
Как работает маска [подробнее здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1862)

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
margin-left: -1em;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 683" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
<defs>
 <pattern id="patt" x="0" y="24" width="160" height="40"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" > 
              <g fill="black"  transform="translate(0,0)" >
  <g fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" >
  <path id="path837" d="M19.8 2.4 35 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M55.8-17.6 71-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path841" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M91.8 2.4 107 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" id="path845" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M127.8-17.6 143-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path847" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path id="path883" d="m55.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m127.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path885" />
  <path id="path887" d="m5.5-3.9 4 2.4V3l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m80-5.7 4 2.4v4.6l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path889" />
  <path id="path891" d="m152.7-5.4 4 2.3v4.7l-4 2.3-4-2.3v-4.7z" />
 </g> 
      </pattern> 
    <mask id="mask" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <rect fill="url(#patt)" x="0" y="380" width="100%" height="40" fill="black"  />
    </mask> 
</defs>          
 
 <image  transform="translate(0,200)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg" y="-200" width="100%" height="100%"  />
               <!-- Add a mask  -->
   <image   mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IAG.png" y="230" width="100%" height="108%" />  
</svg>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг #4.**

Добавляем анимацию перемещения изображения

```
<image  transform="translate(0,200)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg"
  y="-160" width="100%" height="100%">
                <!-- Animation of moving the image -->
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="translate"
     begiin="0s" dur="8s" values="0,0;  0,140;0,140;0,0;0,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </image>
```

Полный код ниже:

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
margin-left: -1em;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 683" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
<defs>
 <pattern id="patt" x="0" y="24" width="160" height="40"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" > 
              <g fill="black"  transform="translate(0,0)" >
  <g fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" >
  <path id="path837" d="M19.8 2.4 35 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M55.8-17.6 71-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path841" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M91.8 2.4 107 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" id="path845" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M127.8-17.6 143-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path847" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path id="path883" d="m55.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m127.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path885" />
  <path id="path887" d="m5.5-3.9 4 2.4V3l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m80-5.7 4 2.4v4.6l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path889" />
  <path id="path891" d="m152.7-5.4 4 2.3v4.7l-4 2.3-4-2.3v-4.7z" />
 </g> 
      </pattern> 
    <mask id="mask" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <rect fill="url(#patt)" x="0" y="382" width="100%" height="40" fill="black"  />
    </mask> 
</defs>          
 
 <image  transform="translate(0,200)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg" y="-160" width="100%" height="100%">
                <!-- Animation of moving the image -->
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="translate" begiin="0s" dur="8s" values="0,0;  0,140;0,140;0,0;0,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </image> 
               <!-- Add a mask  -->
   <image   mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IAG.png" y="230" width="100%" height="108%" >
      
</svg>
</div>
```

**Шаг #5.**

Анимация деталей изображений

Animating image details.

Анимируется SVG фильтр `feTurbulence` для оживления деталей растровых изображений
***Заметьте, что этот шаг не обязателен, так как применение анимации фильтра ресурсоемко***
<sub>(Но выглядит, на мой взгляд красиво)</sub>

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
margin-left: -1em;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 683" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
<defs>
 <pattern id="patt" x="0" y="24" width="160" height="40"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" > 
              <g fill="black"  transform="translate(0,0)" >
  <g fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" >
  <path id="path837" d="M19.8 2.4 35 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M55.8-17.6 71-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path841" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M91.8 2.4 107 11v17.5l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V11.1z" id="path845" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path d="M127.8-17.6 143-9V8.6l-15 8.8-15.2-8.8V-8.9z" id="path847" transform="matrix(.9988 0 0 .95561 0 1.7)" />
  <path id="path883" d="m55.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m127.5 28.1 4 2.4V35l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path885" />
  <path id="path887" d="m5.5-3.9 4 2.4V3l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" />
  <path d="m80-5.7 4 2.4v4.6l-4 2.4-4-2.4v-4.6z" id="path889" />
  <path id="path891" d="m152.7-5.4 4 2.3v4.7l-4 2.3-4-2.3v-4.7z" />
 </g> 
      </pattern> 
    <mask id="mask" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <rect fill="url(#patt)" x="0" y="380" width="100%" height="40" fill="black"  />
    </mask> 
<filter id="fl">
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" />
      <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="10" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>   
</defs>          
 
 <image filter="url(#fl)" transform="translate(0,200)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEe.jpg" y="-160" width="100%" height="100%" overflow:hidden; >
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="translate" begiin="0s" dur="8s" values="0,0;  0,140;0,140;0,0;0,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </image> 
     
  <image  filter="url(#fl)" mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IAG.png" y="230" width="100%" height="108%" />  

</svg>
</div>   
<script>  
 // Animated SVG filter `feTurbulence` to animate bitmap details 
var img = document.querySelector("#fl feTurbulence");
var frames = 0;
var rad = Math.PI / 360;

function AnimateBaseFrequency() {
  bfx = .04;
  bfy = .04;
  frames += 3;
  bfx += 0.01 * Math.sin(frames * rad);
  bfy += 0.01 * Math.cos(frames * rad);
  bf = bfx.toString() + ' ' + bfy.toString();
  img.setAttributeNS(null, 'baseFrequency', bf);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
</script>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70084203/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>